# How to fix Windows scaling issue above 100% for my react.js & tailwind css website?

Tags: reactjs, windows, tailwind-css, scaling, web-frontend

The scaling of my react.js and tailwind css website differs among screens, since my website is scaled for screens that have a default scaling to 100%. This is how the website is supposed to load / look like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rpLE.png)

It loads normally on my HP monitor, where the default system scale settings is set to 100%. However, when I opened the website on my standard dell laptop, where the default system scale settings is set to 150%, the website loads / looks like this, cutting away at some elements on the page. I have to manually zoom out to 67% in order to view the website normally.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOpwN.jpg)

I am new to react.js & tailwind css and feel like I am missing something in my code. I came across this article that explained this exact scenario, but with a 125% scaling and gave some suggestions on fixing it; however, I am finding it difficult to translate that into my own tailwind css code for my website. Again, I feel like I am missing something and I can't figure out what it is. Here is the solution:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wld00.png)

Here is the website: https://silvawebdesigns.com/how-to-fix-windows-scaling-issues-above-100-for-your-website/

My main question is, how can I implement the above solution into my own code? My tailwind.config code looks like this currently:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7f9up.png)